# How to use jQuery UI with vite in laravel 9

Tags: jquery, laravel, jquery-ui

I am learning vite and struck with including jquery-ui into the project.

**libs.ts**

```
import * as jQuery from 'jquery';
declare global {
    interface Window {
        jQuery: typeof jQuery;
        $: typeof jQuery;
    }
}


window.$ = window.jQuery = jQuery;
require('jquery-ui-dist');
```

**main.ts**

```
jQuery(function(){
  console.log("i am called")  // getting console output
  jQuery(".datepicker").datepicker(); // getting error in editor  Property 'datepicker' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'
});
```

**console output**
[image: console output]

**vite.config.js**

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import { esbuildCommonjs } from '@originjs/vite-plugin-commonjs'

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/scss/libs.scss',
                'resources/scss/main.scss',
                'resources/css/app.css',
                'resources/js/libs.ts',
                'resources/js/main.ts',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
    optimizeDeps:{
        esbuildOptions:{
          plugins:[
            esbuildCommonjs(['jquery','jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui'])
          ]
        }
      }
});
```

**package.json**

```
    "devDependencies": {
        "@originjs/vite-plugin-commonjs": "^1.0.3",
        "@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio": "^0.4.0",
        "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.2",
        "@tailwindcss/line-clamp": "^0.4.0",
        "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.4",
        "axios": "^0.25",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.4.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.21",
        "postcss": "^8.1.14",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.1.6",
        "vite": "^2.9.11"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
        "jquery": "^3.6.0",
        "jquery-ui": "^1.13.2",
        "jquery-ui-dist": "^1.13.1",
        "moment": "^2.29.4",
        "sass": "^1.53.0"
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a bit tricky and counterintuitive, but:

1. in your `bootstrap.js` file, import jQuery and manually define a global alias

```
import $ from 'jquery';
window.jQuery = window.$ = $;
```

2. in your `app.js`, import `bootstrap.js` and then directly the `dist` file for jQuery-UI

```
import './bootstrap.js';
import 'jquery-ui/dist/jquery-ui';
```

It is **important** to leave jQuery initialization in `boostrap.js` (or whatever other file imported from the main one before actually importing jQuery-UI), so to enforce entire resolution of jQuery import and global alias definition. Keeping all together in the same file (import jQuery, define the alias, import jQuery-UI) is resolved in a different order, and break things: all imports are managed before execution of other code (e.g. the alias definition), so when it is the turn for jQuery-UI initialization it cannot find the global `$` object.

This solution has been inspired by [this post](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vite/laravel-vite-jquery?page=1&replyId=825619) (it actually works even withot an alias in Vite configuration).

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the typescript types for datetimepicker so TypeScript knows about it

```
npm i @types/jquery.ui.datetimepicker
```

Comment: Why should i include datetimepicker types, when jquery itself is not working

Comment: Well once you get jQuery working you'll end up with typescript errors because it doesn't understand datepicker. As to getting jquery UI working, your issue in the vitejs git repo looks like it has more useful answers